# Is there a way to configure Prometheus to use a Google (Service) Account to authenticate scrape targets

Tags: prometheus, google-authentication

> **Update** Thanks to @levi-harrison, I wrote a solution [gcp-oidc-token-proxy](https://github.com/DazWilkin/gcp-oidc-token-proxy)

I'd like to scrape Cloud Run services that require (Google) authentication but this solution would be generally applicable to any endpoint secured by Google auth'd identities.

Equivalently, I can:

```sh
curl \
--request GET
--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
https://my-server-blahblah-wl.a.run.app/metrics
```

Prometheus supports only (?) TLS or OAuth2.

The [oauth2](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#oauth2) configuration requires a Client ID and secret.

Using a Google Service Account (configured with appropriate IAM permissions) and, following along with Google's [OAuth2 for server-server apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account), I can get the Prometheus config `client_id` (though I'm unclear whether this is the Service Account's key's `client_id` or `client_email`) but I'm unsure what to use for Prometheus config `client_secret` (or `client_secret_file`) and `token_url`.

I've tried using the Service Account's key for `client_secret_file`.

I've tried generating a JWT using [`oauth2l`](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) and using this for `client_secret`:

```sh
oauth2l fetch \
--type=jwt \
--scope cloud-platform \
--credentials ${PWD}/${KEY}.json
```

And I've tried using [`gcloud auth application-default`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default) because `${HOME}/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` because these credentials contain `client_id` and `client_secret`

For `application_default_credentials.json`, I used `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

With the JWT, I've used `https://sts.googleapis.com/v1beta/token`

But, regardless, I get 400s.

I tried using `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=${API_KEY}` with a JWT and get 400 with `INVALID_GRANT_TYPE` because I'm unable to alter the request body to include `grant_type=authorization-code` per [Token Service](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/reference/securetoken/rest/v1/token)

For completeness, `prometheus.yml`:

```
global:
  ...

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "foo"
    scheme: https
    oauth2:
      # From Service Account key
      client_id: ""
      # ID token (JWT) from `oauth2l`
      client_secret: ""
      scopes:
      - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
      token_url: "https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=${API_KEY}"
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "my-server-blahblah-wl.a.run.app"
```

Comment: For scrapes and most other operations, Prometheus supports Basic Authentication, plain `authorization` header configuration, OAuth 2.0, and TLS (see https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/common@v0.31.1/config#HTTPClientConfig).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus OAuth 2.0 authentication specifically supports the [Client Credentials](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4) grant type, which uses the `client_id` and `client_secret` as credentials to request a token from the `token_url`. The Google's OAuth 2.0 guide seems to describe using the [JWT Bearer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7523#section-2.1) grant type, which is not supported by Prometheus.

You might want to look into the [stackdriver_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/stackdriver_exporter), and also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/mrVa9fnZPc8v).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! Yes, I want flexibility on the OAuth config to have Prometheus include `grant_type=authorization-code`. Using Stackdriver would yield metrics but at the expense of an indirection and the cost of that service. I don't understand OAuth sufficiently well to know whether Prometheus' implementation is too limiting or whether providing a generic OAuth client is too challenging.

Comment: Yes, the issue is Prometheus' implementation being too limiting. We don't support the appropriate grant type and field. 

As the person who wrote the OAuth support, I don't think it would be too much of a challenge to add support for Google OAuth 2.0 (the semi-standard library provides a package after all), but I would say it's probably too niche of a use case. I guess you could file an issue if you'd like (https://github.com/prometheus/common/issues).

Comment: Another approach would be using a sidecar to write the token to a file, which could then be picked up by Prometheus. I don't think anything like that exists though.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. The sidecar idea is very interesting and would -- IIUC -- provide a mechanism to simplify the process too because it could take a service account and mint tokens (for Prometheus) on demand. I'm going to give that a try next week and will report back. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Apologies, I don't have another to reach you. I've written the sidecar. I've configured Prometheus to use it as the `token_url`. Prometheus reports `oauth2: server response missing access_token` but the sidecar's logs are returning JSON `{"access_token": ..., "expires_in": 3600, "refresh_token": ..., "token_type": "Bearer"}`. If I use the logged `access_token`, I can `curl` the service directly, I get JSON back and if I `curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN} ...` against the endpoint and receive metrics. Any idea?

Comment: I'm an idiot.... `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")`. It's working

Comment: Yeah, that would do it. I don't check Stackoverflow that often so if you need to reach me again you can send an email to the address listed on my GitHub profile (https://github.com/leviharrison).